# $k$-form on $\mathbb{P}^n(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

Let $\pi$ be the canonical projection from $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}/\{0\}$ to $\mathbb{P}^n(\mathbb{R})$. Given a $k$-form $\alpha$ on $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}/\{0\}$ find necessary and sufficient conditions such that there exists a $k$-form $\beta$ on $\mathbb{P}^n(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\alpha = \pi^* \beta$.

What I have done: In order to let $\alpha$ be the pullback we should check that $\alpha$ remains the same along lines. Thus for example if $\alpha = f(x,y)dxdy$ we must have

$f(x,y)dxdy = f(\lambda x, \lambda y)d(\lambda x)d(\lambda y) = \lambda^2f(\lambda x, \lambda y)dxdy$.

Comment: Once correctly stated you have found the necessary *and* sufficient condition. Now prove it! (If you write up your solution as an answer I will upvote it.)